# Python Tweepy rate limit keeps being reached

Tags: python, tweepy

I've finished building a Twitter bot... Or so I thought I had been.  Now, whenever I try to run the program, after about 20 minutes it warns me: "Rate limit reached. Sleeping for: 445."  I am using the sleep method and wait_on_rate_limit=True parameter and I am still getting the warning/error.

It sleeps for 23 seconds after each request.

Does anyone know a way around this or how to rectify this problem?  Is there a certain number of minutes I must wait between each request so I don't run into this ordeal over and over again?

Comment: Isn't that just [Twitter limiting](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limits) you?

Comment: I believe you can request higher limits than these: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limits

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read tags before using them. [tag:computer-science] is for theoretical questions, primarily. Thanks!